# Stuck box using IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, box

How can I fix this skewed search "box" and "amusing border, after select" problem in IE or Chrome browser? This should remain constant in css, mandatory!:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

[Example here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/p4p98o5y/)

**Special thanks to [ze-rubeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4232386/ze-rubeus) for the help to solve all problems!**

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify the issue because it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Skewed box and ugly border after select item! Working perfectly without *, ..., but i need to keep it in css!

Comment: I can only suggest you demo the problem because it's still not clear.

Comment: it's clear the problem is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution to this drama :

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

add `outline:0` to remove this ugly border forever  **[LIVE DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/p4p98o5y/2/)**

Or you can just target this rule and apply `outline : 0` :

```
*:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/p4p98o5y/3/)**

in IE9 it does't allow you to remove this out line until you use this html tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Comment: Yes, outline problem is SOLVED, but search box still Skewed!

Comment: i don't know what version of IE you are using but this solution works with all browsers